# How to add a Custom Windows Forms Control into Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, custom-controls

I want to add my custom control into the VS Toolbox. But I need it to appear in toolbox always when a new project is open. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a VSIX package to install the control**

You can create a *VSIX* package to distribute and install user controls to toolbox.

To do so, you can create a *VSIX Project* and add a *Windows Forms ToolBox Control* to the project. The control is decorated with a `ProvideToolboxControl` attribute which determines the tab that the control will appear in. You can pass an existing or a new tab name to the attribute:

```
[ProvideToolboxControl("Some Tab Name", false)]
public partial class ToolboxControl1 : UserControl
```

You can also fill the information in `.vsixmanifest` file. Then when you build the project, it creates a `.vsix` package file in `\bin\debug` folder of the project which you can distribute this file. If you run the file, it installs the control in visual studio toolbox.

*More information:*

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Forms Toolbox Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-windows-forms-toolbox-control)

*Note:*

- VS 2013 has a *Windows Forms ToolBox Control Project* Template under extensibility group of new project window and you can use it to create the project. Starting from VS 2015 you should use *VSIX Project* template.

**Manually Add Control to Toolbox**

You can copy the dll of your control to a permanent location. Then right click on ToolBox, for example on general tab, then click `Choose Items ...` then in Choose Toolbox Items window in `.Net Framework Components` Tab, click `Browse...` button and open the dll of your control. Then in the components list, check the control and click `OK` button. The control will appear under the selected tab. You also can add your own tab simply by right click and choose `Add Tab`.