# What determines where a Usercontrol appears in Toolbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have added Usercontrols from a library I have created by right-clicking in the Toolbox and selecting "Choose Items...".
The added Usercontrols appear under "Data". Why? How can I change that?

Comment: You can add them anywhere you like.  So you probably had the Data tab selected when you right-clicked the toolbox.  Maybe you like creating your own tab, use the "Add Tab" context menu item first.  Maybe you'd prefer the toolbox to auto-populate, just build the project after adding the reference to the library.

Comment: [How to add a Custom Windows Forms Control into Visual Studio Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36097875/3110834)