# VS suddenly refuses to show usercontrols

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, user-controls, toolbox

I have a winforms project and I also have a dll with own made usercontrols.

- What I did was start a new winforms project
- In the toolbox right mouse
  `choose items`
- browse to myControls.dll
- all controls are found and checked, then I click on `OK`

This worked on friday, and I was able to drag some controls on my form.
But today the controls are gone again.
So I repeat all the steps from above but it does not helps anymore

What I tried :

- in toolbox right mouse `show all`
- Checked `Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer` that the property `Automatically Populate Toolbox` is set to true
- Rebuild the project
- Reloaded the project
- Restarted VS
- Checked the target and framework are the same for the project and the dll
- Reset Toolbox

Nothing helps, the controls just refuse to show up.

What can cause a dll with usercontrols to load in the Toolbox one day and not anymore the next day ?
Nothing has changed in the library and nothing has changed in the winforms project.  I just shut down VS and came back to work again today and found it like this.

Also, the usercontrols are used in several other projects without any troubles

EDIT:
The controls I was able to drag on the form on friday are all working without problems. So I guess there really is nothing wrong with the dll.

EDIT:
in other winforms projects the controls do still show up in the toolbox. Just as they did in this project on friday...

Answer (score 0):

OK I found what happened here,
it seems the controls in `myControls.dll` where added to the toolbox after all, but for some reason where put into an other already existing tab (DX18.1 Data & Analytics).

I had to manually create the correct tab and drag all controls there myself.

This worked for me and I put this as answer for anybody else with the same problem, but I still have no clue how this was possible.

Comment: You can [distribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098139/3110834) your controls using a VSIX package.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks I was also looking for a way to install it so I don't have to do it again for every new project. I already thought it was not possible again in VS