# Distributing .Net controls

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have developed custom controls using Vb.Net. Now I want to distribute my controls for other developers to use them but the only option I know is to import the .dll file into controls in Visual Studio. Is there a way of easily distributing them such as making an installer and register all the controls into VS automatically?

Comment: [How to add a Custom Windows Forms Control into Visual Studio Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098139/3110834)

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want to distribute with the applications you have already made (as in the clients) or just for you as the designer in all of your applications you are developing?

Comment: I just want to distribute my controls for other developers to use.

Comment: @AlbertAlberto Read my answer below, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer using [NuGet.org](https://NuGet.org) for distribution. It is available in VSCode, Visual Studio as part of standart package manager for solution

You can generate deployment packages and deploy your assemblies to remote repositaries with public or optionally private acceess. To do so you have to ship you source code as a standalone package to one of the repositaries [GitHub](https://GitHub.org),[GitLab](https://Gitlab.com), or Azure

[image: Uploading packages to NuGet package manager]

1. For component distribution you can use [NuGet](https://nuget.org),  [MyGet](https://myget.org), [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode)
2. For application distibution you can use [ClickOnce
   deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment)

To do so, register account in GitHub, Google, or Microsoft, register on NuGet and upload generated by you CI/D pipline package manally, or as a part on continious deployment pipeline

Comment: Do you have any other recommendation to on how to create an installer/executable like in https://www.devexpress.com/ or https://www.grapecity.com/en/componentone

Comment: NuGe/MyGet or VSCode marketplace doesn't have anything to do with '*making an installer and register all the controls into VS automatically*'.

Comment: VSIX package is what you are looking for. The linked post has descried how you can create a VSIX package to distribute the control.