# Distributing a User Control (Windows Form Control Library)

Tags: c#, controls, vsix

I have made a user control for the other programmers here, starting with the "Windows Forms Control Library" template - it is my understanding that this is the approach one is supposed to take when creating a user control. It works fine on my machine, I can add it to the toolbar just by going to the toolbar and selecting "Choose Items".  No problems, it's added and I can use it.

I am trying to give it to another developer here.  It's early days in the development process right now, and just to get something going, we have access to a shared directory.  He's compiled the source himself and tried to add the control to his toolbox.  When he tries this, all he gets in the message "There are no components in [my control] that can be placed on the toolbar".

I have found information on distributing user controls over the web, but we want these controls kept in-house.  I've got something called "vsix" installed/updated on my machine, but when I "Export" it, I just get a zip file containing the files he already has. I've tried variations on a search for things like "visual studio 2017 distribute user control" but it keeps coming back to setting up web controls or "use vsix", which I just can't make heads or tails of.

I saw in [How to add a Custom Windows Forms Control into Visual Studio Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097875/how-to-add-a-custom-windows-forms-control-into-visual-studio-toolbox/36098139#36098139) this answer:
"You can copy the dll of your control to a permanent location. Then right-click on ToolBox, for example on the general tab, then click Choose Items ... then in Choose Toolbox Items window in.Net Framework Components Tab, click Browse... button and open the dll of your control. Then in the components list, check the control and click OK button. The control will appear under the selected tab. You also can add your own tab simply by right click and choose Add Tab."
 -- but as soon as we click on it, that's when we get the "There are no components..." message.

So, how do I take a user control I've created on my machine and get it to the guys in the cubes around me?

Is there an "explain it to me like I'm five" version of "Give someone the control you wrote"?

Comment: I did this a long time ago, so the details may have changed, but you need to add a reference to the registry with the path to the folder that contains your assembly(ies).  Something like `[HKLM|HKCU]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\MyFolder`.   Check the registry on your dev machine and you'll no doubt find some examples.  Typically you do this by providing an msi installer that installs your controls and creates the necessary registry entries.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ashkan!  It turns out that there was just some sort of problem on the target computer.  I did eventually move everything over to a Class Library for ease of deployment, but two other people here were able to use what I had without any problems.  So, in the end, we updated and reset some things on the target computer and switched to a Class Library - and the problem was solved!